# Múltiplos inserts inner join PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Olá,

Tenho no DB as tabelas `categoria` e `imagens`

Atualmente a function (no PHP) para inserir na tabela categoria esta similar a isto (somente titulo mesmo):

```
public function insere($ttitulo)
{


try
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO categoria (titulo) VALUES(:titulo)");
        $stmt->bindparam(":titulo",$ttitulo);                   
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();  
        return false;
    }

}
```

No html, Tenho um form com titulo e possibilidade de inserção de até 5 imagens.

O titulo quero que vá para a tabela categoria, até aqui ok, as imagens devem ir para a tabela imagens, um id para cada imagem deve ser criado nesse único submit mas com inner join (ou similar) que possibilite inserir o id da categoria criada juntamente com as imagens.

Na tabela imagens as colunas estão assim:

```
id_imagem | categoria_ID | dir_imagem
```

dir imagem é imagem propriamente dita que vai vir do formulario (já consigo inserir no form a url de cada imagem)

A duvida é como em um unico submit inserir os ids na tabela imagens conforme a quantidade de imagens no formulário e o id da categoria criada, usando o mesmo formulário, preencher a coluna categoria_ID na tabela imagens.

O máximo que consegui tentar:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO categoria (titulo) VALUES(:titulo)");

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id_imagens FROM imagens WHERE id_categoria = id_imagens ");
```

Mas ainda não esta claro para mim

Agradeço ajuda

Comment: Por qual motivo estão negativando minha duvida? Posso reformular ou acrescentar mais informações

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mas entendo que a pergunta está um pouco confusa. Você está misturando mais de uma dúvida na questão só. A começar por relacionamento, que é um problema de SQL, depois tem o submit, que é um problema de HTML e PHP, e fala em IDs que não sabemos de onde vem. Tem muita informação na pergunta, mas não dá pra saber o que é importante e o que não é, e nem o que você conseguiu fazer e onde exatamente está sua dúvida. Sugeriria simplificar a dúvida e resolver o problema um passo por vez (não é uma crítica, apenas estou apontando o que vi como leitor).

Comment: Obrigada @Bacco tentei ser mais clara e fazer entender como uma unica pergunta focada no código php com instruções sql

Comment: O código é importante, mas mais importante que isso é explicar bem o resultado a ser obtido. Tente pensar em qual é o primeiro passo pra resolver seu problema, e [edit] a pergunta para refletir este passo em especial. Uma vez vencido o passo, você pode fazer nova pergunta com o passo seguinte. Uma dica é se por no lugar de quem está lendo, e não faz a mínima idéia do que você está fazendo, e vai ter que entender só pelo que estiver na pergunta :)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, sua intenção é inserir um registro na tabela categoria. Em seguida, utilizar o código do registro inserido durante um loop (ou algo assim), que irá inserir o caminho para os arquivos de imagens em outra tabela.

Estou imaginando que suas duas tabelas provavelmente possuam como chave primária, uma coluna com numeração automática.

Uma opção rápida para fazer isso, é após o `INSERT` da categoria, utilizar o [lastInsertId()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php) para recuperar o ID do último registro inserido. Tendo em mãos o ID da categoria, você pode utilizá-lo para realizar o `INSERT` das imagens.

```
$id_categoria = 0; // Variável para armazenar o ID da categoria.

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO categoria (titulo) VALUES(:titulo)");
$stmt->bindparam(":titulo",$ttitulo);                   

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $id_categoria = (int) $this->db->lastInsertId();
}

// Com o valor de $id_categoria, basta realizar o INSERT das imagens.
$caminho_imagem = "/caminho/para/a/imagem.jpg";
$sql_imagem = "INSERT INTO imagens (categoria_ID, dir_imagem)  
                   VALUES(:categoria, :dir_imagem)"; 

$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql_imagem);
$stmt->bindparam(":categoria",$id_categoria, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindparam(":dir_imagem",$caminho_imagem, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    // Registro inserido com sucesso.
}
```

Na documentação tem mais detalhes sobre o [lastInsertId()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php), vale a pena dar uma conferida.